# Why exoplayer setPlayWhenReady(false) method not pause song?

Tags: android, service, exoplayer

My app plays a streaming song via Exoplayer with service(Notification).
So my player has simple Play/Pause button and its handle with service.
and for play and resume I use setPlayWhenReady() method with passing true/false value. When I load song its play very well but its not pause when I clicked on pause button, I used setPlayWhenReady(false) to pause an exoplayer.
Can somebody help me? about this issue.

Please check this [Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EVL68pDY5gFNZVunmOKoV5Uw9U18pZ6R/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @amin updated my answer